# Razer Core X eGPU not working in Thinkpad + Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, thunderbolt

I've just connected a Razor Core X with an eGPU to my Thinkpad for the first time. The fans are spinning, but `nvidia-smi` doesn't show the eGPU.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check `dmesg | tail -n 200`. It might show something like this:

```
[   74.959198] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: current switch config:
[   74.959201] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Switch: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 2)
[   74.959202] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max Port Number: 11
[   74.959203] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Config:
[   74.959204] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:    Upstream Port Number: 1 Depth: 1 Route String: 0x3 Enabled: 1, PlugEventsDelay: 254ms
[   74.959205] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:    unknown1: 0x0 unknown4: 0x0
[   74.999560] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3: reading drom (length: 0x56)
[   75.301575] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3: uid: 0x1279cc9b0ba8400
[   75.301686] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Port 0: 8086:15d3 (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[   75.301689] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 7/7
[   75.301692] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max counters: 8
[   75.301694] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[   75.302174] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Port 1: 8086:15d3 (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[   75.302178] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 15/15
[   75.302180] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max counters: 16
[   75.302183] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x7800000
[   75.302681] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Port 2: 8086:15d3 (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[   75.302683] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 15/15
[   75.302685] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max counters: 16
[   75.302687] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x0
[   75.302689] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:3: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302691] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:4: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302692] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:5: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302806] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Port 6: 8086:15d3 (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: PCIe (0x100102))
[   75.302808] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 8/8
[   75.302809] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[   75.302811] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[   75.302960] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:  Port 7: 8086:15d3 (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: PCIe (0x100101))
[   75.302962] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 8/8
[   75.302964] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[   75.302966] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[   75.302967] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:8: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302969] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:9: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302971] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:a: disabled by eeprom
[   75.302973] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: 3:b: disabled by eeprom
```

That suggests a permissions/security issue.

Let's install Thunderbolt Admin Tools so we can fix it:

```
sudo apt install thunderbolt-tools
```

Now, let's check to see if Thunderbolt sees the dock:

```
root@mymachine:~# tbtadm devices
0-4 Razer Core X  non-authorized  not in ACL
```

It does!

Now, let's authorize the dock:

```
tbtadm approve 0-4
```

This shows:

```
Authorizing "/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-4"
Already in ACL
system:5 Input/output error
```

Unplugging and replugging the dock and looking at `dmesg` again shows:

```
[11187.232181] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: PCIe tunnel creation failed
```

So we look at Thunderbolt again:

```
root@mymachine:~# tbtadm devices
0-4 Razer Core X  non-authorized  in ACL
```

And, indeed, we can see that the dock is connected:

```
root@mymachine:~# tbtadm acl
0XXXXXb0-XXXX-XXXX-ffff-ffffffffffff  Razer Core X  connected
```

Let's try to authorize things manually:

```
root@mymachine:~# echo '1' > /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-4/authorized 
-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

At this point, I suspected the BIOS might be the issue. So, restart, pull up the BIOS setup. It's in "User Authorization", but let's use the nuclear "No Security" option (probably good to figure out how to lock things down again later):
[image: BIOS Thunderbolt Setup]

At this point, boot the machine again.

Before plugging in the GPU, ensure you have the Nvidia drivers loaded:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia-uvm
```

And try to find the GPU:

```
nvidia-smi
```

Success!

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.00    Driver Version: 418.87.00    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:3D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 15%   36C    P0     1W / 250W |      0MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

According to [this document](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t470s_ug_en.pdf) the BIOS settings mean:

- **No Security**: Allow Thunderbolt devices to be connected automatically.
- **User Authorization**: Allow Thunderbolt devices to be connected after user authorization.
- **Secure Connect**: Allow Thunderbolt devices to be connected with a saved key that has been approved by the user.
- **Display Port and USB**: Allow only Display outputs and USB devices to be connected. Thunderbolt devices are not allowed to be connected