# How do I determine the speed of a Thunderbolt cable connection to an eGPU?

Tags: debian, thunderbolt, lubuntu

I've just bought a new cable to connect my machine to my eGPU and connected it following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/1475192/razer-core-x-egpu-not-working-in-thinkpad-lubuntu-18-04/1475193#1475193). The cable claims it operates at 40 Gbps. How do I verify that it's doing so?

I am using Lubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `lspci` to find details about how the eGPU has connected through the cable.

```bsh
sudo lspci -vv | grep -A 80 -i 2080
```

In the above, you need `sudo` to see the full details and `2080` should be some identifier which you expect to match your eGPU. In my case I'm using an RTX 2080 Ti, so "2080" is a good search term.

The result looks like the following:

```
3d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at 8c000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 4020000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at 4030000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at 6000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 8d000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop- FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <16us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x4 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
             10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Via message, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [258 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=255us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1- ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1-
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=0ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=10us
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn-, PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: 0
    Capabilities: [bb0 v1] Resizable BAR <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

The useful parts are:

```
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <16us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x4 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
```

Here **LnkCap** means the capability of the highest rating of the link and **LnkSta** means the status of the actual current operating speeds. The unit **GT/s** standards for [gigatransfers per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_(computing)).

Checking the "8GT/s, Width x16" specs against a [list of PCI-E versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions) we see that this is PCI 3.0 x16 with an estimated 15.754 GB/s.

However, note that the connection's actual status is "downgraded". This is because PCI-E has a limited number of lanes that are distributed across the machine's devices. In my Thinkpad P1 Gen1, the PCI-E has 16 lanes (the "x16" above), but 4 of these go to my on-board GPU, 4 go to my hard drive, and 4 go to both of my two thunderbolt ports.

Thus, the one thunderbolt port I use to connect to my eGPU has:

```
Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x4 (downgraded)
```

Given that, my machine limits me to slower speeds than 40Gbps and I could probably get a cheaper, but much longer, 20Gbps cable.